# How can I use a .Net assembly in Java

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio-2010, assemblies

I want to use a Microsoft .Net Assembly in a Java Application. Is there any way out to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java and .Net run an fundamentally different systems: the JVM and CLR respectively.  It's not possible to directly load one into the other and use it.  They are incompatible formats.

It is possible though to have .Net and Java components interact through a bridge layer.  There are several out there which provide this behavior

- http://www.jnbridge.com/
- http://java-dotnet-bridge.com/

Note: Most of these solutions though are aimed at sharing well defined components as opposed to directly loading libraries.  This may or may not work for you.

Comment: Thanks JaredPar. Actually, I have a .Net Assembly containing my Entity Classes and I want to use that same Entity Classes in the Java Application. Is there any way that I can reference my Entities Assembly (.dll) in my Java Application?

Comment: @Baig, no. There is no way to directly reference a .Net DLL in Java

Answer (score 1):

Something interesting on the same topic: [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/)