# using reflection on .net assembly from java

Tags: java, c#, .net, java-8

I am writing a code in java in which i need to pass the path to a .Net assembly (.dll or .exe). Is there a java equivalent of Assembly.Load("~\abc.dll") in c# to analyze namespaces, classes and methods(basically reflection)

Comment: you're asking for too much, I can only tell that this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826391/how-can-i-use-a-net-assembly-in-java , this is for calling methods from C# not for getting `Method` objects from them but you may be able to do the reflection on C# and pass its results to java through the bridge

Comment: anyway can you tell us your goal of this ?

Comment: this link may be help you:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ajyadav123/invoking-java-code-in-C-Sharp-net/

Comment: Thanks @amin. This article is great!

Comment: @niceman, the above article pointed me to a bridge(Jni4net), an open source project available on - "https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net". This is what i wanted